# $push string as an array in mongo document

Tags: mongodb, go, graphql-go

I'm having trouble understanding arrays in Go, especially with both graphql and mongo. With JS this all would've been a breeze for me, but I'm wondering if you can look at what I have and point out the obvious!

I'm looking for an object to be shaped like the following:

```
time
├── login
│   ├── 0
│   │   └── "2021-08-16T20:11:54-07:00"
│   ├── 1
│   │   └── "2021-08-16T20:11:54-07:00"
│   └── 2
        └── "2021-08-16T20:11:54-07:00"
```

models.go:

```golang
type Time struct {
    Login []string
}

type User struct {
    ID       graphql.ID
    Time     Time
}
```

schema.graphql:

```
type Time {
  login: [String!]!
}

type User {
  id:      ID!
  time:    Time!
}
```

database.go:

```golang
filter := bson.D{{Key: "email", Value: email}}
arr := [1]string{time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)}
update := bson.D{
  {Key: "$push", Value: bson.D{
    {Key: "time.login", Value: arr},
  }},
}
result, err := collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
```

I've also tried:

```golang
update := bson.D{
  {Key: "$push", Value: bson.D{
    {Key: "time.login", Value: time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)},
  }},
}
result, err := collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
```

But always end up with the same error:

`error="write exception: write errors: [The field 'time.login' must be an array but is of type null in document {_id: ObjectId('611b28fabffe7f3694bc86dc')}]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[1]string{}` is an array. `[]string{}` is a slice. The two are different. An array is a fixed size object. A slice can grow/shrink dynamically.

In this case, you should not be using either, because `$push` gets a value, not a slice:

```
update := bson.D{
  {Key: "$push", Value: bson.D{
    {Key: "time.login", Value: time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)},
  }},
}
```

Comment: that was what I've tried first, and I've gotten the same error with it!

Comment: That means you already inserted the document with `time.login:null`. Insert the document without the time field. Use the bson `omitempty` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the slice.
And use append.